# SSO using Apache Directory and Apache Camel

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, apache-camel, middleware, restful-architecture

I implemented an Apache Camel based middleware application to manage authentication, authorization and also to dispatch the front end application calls to my several RESTful back end web services. I'm using Apache Directory as my Ldap server for authentication but I'm using it separately for each back end service.

My question is how to implement a single sign on SSO system to all my back end services.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this question is related to Camel directly.
If you want to build a SSO system, I think you can take a look at the [oauth](http://oauth.net/). Then you can pass the token as http uri parameter across the back end services.

Comment: I'm still trying to choose between oauth and SAML, because I'm using WSO2 Identity Server for authentication & resource(service) authorisation so I'm trying to do it within WSO2IS.